# auto deployment of war file on tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war

I have tomcat 6 running on windows 7. When I deploy a war file (foo.war as an example) inside of webapps folder, it does auto deploy however if I want to re-deploy same war file, the server reports an error:

```
SEVERE: Context [/foo] startup failed due to previous errors
```

When I reviewed localhost.log file, following exception is recorded.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: no web.xml present
```

However if I follow steps as below everything is fine, I mean deploying/accessing foo application just fine.

1. shutdown tomcat server
2. **remove foo folder and foo.war file under webapps folder**
3. re-start tomcat server
4. deploy foo.war file (drag and drop)

Is there way that I don't have to shutdown/re-start the server every time I have to re-deploy foo.war?

[update]

[image]

index.xhtml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head><!-- requires head to load JS/CSS for primefaces --></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet name="creds/css/creds.css" /> <!-- Should be here inside      of h:body -->
<p:layout fullPage="true">
     <p:layoutUnit position="north">
        north
    </p:layoutUnit>>
    <p:layoutUnit position="south">
       south
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="320">
        west
    </p:layoutUnit>  
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        center
    </p:layoutUnit>    
</p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Specific Tomcat version? Hint: you should be using the latest one, which is currently 6.0.44. And you should start thinking about upgrading to Tomcat 8.0.x.

Comment: @Christopher: Thank you for your reply. I am using 6.0.37 for now as a test bed. I would like to interpret your statement as 6.0.44 will do clean remove prior deployment of foo.war if I drag/drop new copy of foo.war into webapps folder.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you were using a recent version of Tomcat 6. Tomcat 6 is quite old, so small changes in version numbers sometimes mean years of time passing between them. Anyhow, *does* your web application have a `META-INF/web.xml` file in it?

Comment: i see. yes it does have web.xml in WEB-INF. Someone could correct me on following statement of mine, but a long ago when i deployed a war file on tomcat 6(?) in linux platform i don't remember i had to manually shutdown/restart the app server. i could simply drop it and the app server cleanly removed old one and installed new. thank you for your taking time for reading this thread. it is just matter of convenience for me. i will consider to migrate to tomcat 8. have a blessed day!

Comment: Tomcat will still autp-update. But it seems like what you are saying is that Tomcat complains about a missing `web.xml` file. Actually, it's not Tomcat complaining... it's Java Faces. Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: i just posted it in update section. thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this has nothing to do with Tomcat or WAR-file deployment. Replace all your tags with "java serverfaces" and see if anyone bites.

Comment: forgive me. what it means by replacing all tags with "javaserverfaces"? i post index.xhtml file foo.war contains in update section.

Comment: I meant in the "tags" for your question here on SO. This is a Java ServerFaces question, not an Apache Tomcat question.